# angular2 test, how do I mock sub component

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jasmine, angular, components

How do I mock sub component in jasmine tests?

I have `MyComponent`, which uses `MyNavbarComponent` and `MyToolbarComponent`

```js
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MyNavbarComponent} from './my-navbar.component';
import {MyToolbarComponent} from './my-toolbar.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <my-toolbar></my-toolbar>
    {{foo}}
    <my-navbar></my-navbar>
  `,
  directives: [MyNavbarComponent, MyToolbarComponent]
})
export class MyComponent {}
```

When I test this component, I do not want to load and test those two sub components; MyNavbarComponent, MyToolbarComponent, so I want to mock it.

I know how to mock with services using `provide(MyService, useClass(...))`, but I have no idea how to mock directives; components;

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    setBaseTestProviders(
      TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
      TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
    );

    //TODO: want to mock unnecessary directives for this component test
    // which are MyNavbarComponent and MyToolbarComponent
  })

  it('should bind to {{foo}}', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(MyComponent).then((fixture) => {
      let DOM = fixture.nativeElement;
      let myComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
      myComponent.foo = 'FOO';
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(DOM.innerHTML).toMatch('FOO');
    });
  });
```

Here is my plunker example;

http://plnkr.co/edit/q1l1y8?p=preview

Comment: The components are working fine, your issue is another thing. You're importing, for example, `MyNavbarComponent` but in your component class is called `myNavbarComponent`. Note the lowercase `m`, that makes it fail. If you uppercase it it will work fine.

Comment: thanks @EricMartinez, I fixed lowercase and the test works. However my question is still valid with how to mock a component. I am testing `MyComponent`, not `MyNavbarComponent` nor `MyToolbarComponent`

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. You can take a look at this [spec](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9e44dd85ada181b11be869841da2c157b095ee07/modules/angular2/test/testing/test_component_builder_spec.ts#L152) and see how they mock the component.

Comment: @EricMartinez, thanks. I posted my own answer learned from your commnet. All credit goes to you.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

As requested, I'm posting another answer about how to mock sub components with `input`/`output`:

So Lets start by saying we have `TaskListComponent` that displays tasks, and refreshes whenever one of them is clicked:

```html
<div id="task-list">
  <div *ngFor="let task of (tasks$ | async)">
    <app-task [task]="task" (click)="refresh()"></app-task>
  </div>
</div>
```

`app-task` is a sub component with the `[task]`  input and the `(click)`  output.

Ok great, now we want to write tests for my `TaskListComponent` and of course we don't want to test the real `app-task`component.

so as @Klas suggested we can configure our `TestModule` with:

```js
schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
```

We might not get any errors at either build or runtime, but we won't be able to test much other than the existence of the sub component.

**So how can we mock sub components?**

First we'll define a mock directive for our sub component (same selector):

```js
@Directive({
  selector: 'app-task'
})
class MockTaskDirective {
  @Input('task')
  public task: ITask;
  @Output('click')
  public clickEmitter = new EventEmitter<void>();
}
```

Now we'll declare it in the testing module:

```js
let fixture : ComponentFixture<TaskListComponent>;
let cmp : TaskListComponent;

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [TaskListComponent, **MockTaskDirective**],
    // schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: TasksService,
        useClass: MockService
      }
    ]
  });

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TaskListComponent);
  **fixture.autoDetectChanges();**
  cmp = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```

- Notice that because the generation of sub component of the fixture is happening asynchronously after its creation, we activate its autoDetectChanges  feature.

In our tests, we can now query for the directive, access its DebugElement's injector, and get our mock directive instance through it:

```js
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';    
const mockTaskEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockTaskDirective));
const mockTaskCmp = mockTaskEl.injector.get(MockTaskDirective) as MockTaskDirective;
```

[This part should usually be in the `beforeEach` section, for cleaner code.]

From here, the tests are a piece of cake :)

```js
it('should contain task component', ()=> {
  // Arrange.
  const mockTaskEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockTaskDirective));

  // Assert.
  expect(mockTaskEl).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should pass down task object', ()=>{
  // Arrange.
  const mockTaskEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockTaskDirective));
  const mockTaskCmp = mockTaskEl.injector.get(MockTaskDirective) as MockTaskDirective;

  // Assert.
  expect(mockTaskCmp.task).toBeTruthy();
  expect(mockTaskCmp.task.name).toBe('1');
});

it('should refresh when task is clicked', ()=> {
  // Arrange
  spyOn(cmp, 'refresh');
  const mockTaskEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockTaskDirective));
  const mockTaskCmp = mockTaskEl.injector.get(MockTaskDirective) as MockTaskDirective;

  // Act.
  mockTaskCmp.clickEmitter.emit();

  // Assert.
  expect(cmp.refresh).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: You may want to have an example where `fixture.detectChanges()` is called. My app's sub-component's data was only set on a method call so in order to get this example working for me I had to call the method on the fixture and then call `detectChanges()` for it to work.

Comment: Is By.directive something that needs to be imported separately to be used? - I'm getting an error in my Karma test saying: "ReferenceError: By is not defined"

Comment: @Alex I was wondering the same thing.. `import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';` worked for me.

Comment: What a great answer. Saved me a lot of time!

Comment: This solution however wont solve the problem when parent use @ViewChild(SubComponent). Still waiting for Angular team to resolve this

Comment: can you link to the open issue?

Comment: @Nicolas, I just use local variables to solve the problem. `@ViewChild('my-sub-component')` works if you have `#my-sub-component` as an attribute to the sub-component.

Answer (score 28):

If you use `schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]`in `TestBed` the component under test will not load sub components.

```js
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyComponent } from './my.component';

describe('App', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed
      .configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [
          MyComponent
        ],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
      });
  });

  it(`should have as title 'app works!'`, async(() => {
    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    let app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('Todo List');
  }));

});
```

This works in the released version of Angular 2.0.
[Full code sample here](https://github.com/Mellbourn/ng2-todo/blob/master/src/app/app.component.spec.ts).

An alternative to `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA` is `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA`

Comment: what if the sub component has an input/output property and i want to create a mock for it to put spies on?

Comment: @baryo in that case I would not recommend the path I have suggested in my answer, since those components will be completely ignored.

Comment: roger that. do you know a way to achieve that thought?

Comment: ok, i found a way: you create a mock directive with the same inputs/outputs & selector as the real subcomponent, and add it to the test module's declaration instead of the real one. now in the test itself you can access its instance like the following: `fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(MockSubComponent)).injector.get(MockSubComponent)` . Cheers!

Comment: @baryo That sounds great! Could you post a plunkr? Or another answer to this question?

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Eric Martinez, I found this solution.

We can use `overrideDirective` function which is documented here, 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/testing/TestComponentBuilder-class.html

It takes three prarmeters;
1. Component to implement
2. Child component to override
3. Mock component

Resolved solution is here at http://plnkr.co/edit/a71wxC?p=preview

This is the code example from the plunker

```js
import {MyNavbarComponent} from '../src/my-navbar.component';
import {MyToolbarComponent} from '../src/my-toolbar.component';

@Component({template:''})
class EmptyComponent{}

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
    return tcb
      .overrideDirective(MyComponent, MyNavbarComponent, EmptyComponent)
      .overrideDirective(MyComponent, MyToolbarComponent, EmptyComponent)
      .createAsync(MyComponent)
      .then((componentFixture: ComponentFixture) => {
        this.fixture = componentFixture;
      });
  ));

  it('should bind to {{foo}}', () => {
    let el = this.fixture.nativeElement;
    let myComponent = this.fixture.componentInstance;
    myComponent.foo = 'FOO';
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(el.innerHTML).toMatch('FOO');    
  });
});
```

Comment: Good to know it helped!

Comment: Does karma-babel correctly handle `@Component` annotation? Can you post your karma.conf?
I get `[preprocessor.babel]: Unexpected token` on that line

Comment: How can this be done in Angular ^2.0.0 with `TestBed`?

Comment: @PhilipBulley see my answer

Comment: There were some typos in that plunkr. Also have to actually declare same selector name to override existing one. updated version is here http://plnkr.co/edit/56u5sUgnEbiY8CPNhzq0?p=preview

Comment: so how do you spy on one of the mocked sub components methods? If it had one that is..

Comment: @ KlasMellbourn where about, more exactly, is this answer?

Comment: `TestComponentBuilder` is however deprecated the new `TestBed. overrideDirective` only allow override metadata

Answer (score 6):

I put together a simple `MockComponent` module to help make this a little easier:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyComponent } from './src/my.component';
import { MockComponent } from 'ng2-mock-component';

describe('MyComponent', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyComponent,
        MockComponent({ 
          selector: 'my-subcomponent', 
          inputs: ['someInput'], 
          outputs: [ 'someOutput' ]
        })
      ]
    });

    let fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
    ...
  });

  ...
});
```

It's available at 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-mock-component.

Comment: This will not work if the component have something like this `@ViewChild(SubComponent) sc; sc.callFn()`. Component injector will not recognize `SubComponent` with your mock replacement and will always return null. One solution is to tag it but tagging wont work with `@ContentChild` or dynamic sub components :/

Comment: @Nicolas won't this also be a problem with baryo's solution?, now I have done some digging these two solutions look very similar. I only ask because I first read the comment as a hint this solution wasn't as good as the others but Im still learning angular.

Comment: @rgammans Yes his solution is nothing more than overriding the tag or selector. When doing something like @ViewChild(SubComponent) it will not work sine the real component will always point to the SubComponent and not let say MockTaskDirective

Comment: Let's say in the real component 'someOutput' is EventEmitter<bool>. Is it possible to emit it inside the unit test using 'ng2-mock-component'?